# BIRT, round up/append 59 seconds to date/time parameter?

Tags: birt, seconds

Have a date/time field in this format in the database:  2018-12-10 15:45:00.075444

Have a parameter query that is searching between a beginning date and ending date.  I do not want the user to have to enter the seconds part.

This is the format of what's being entered:  2023-02-17 23:59

BIRT seems to be appending :00 to the parameter for seconds.  This is great for the beginning date, however I need the ending date to be appended with :59.  :00 in this case would omit records from 0-59 seconds which is not desirable in this case.

I tried using JavaScript to edit the end date and append it but no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

> BIRT seems to be appending :00 to the parameter for seconds.

No, BIRT just interpretes the date/time correct. Of course the effect is the same.

I'd recommend to use half-open intervals for the beginnging and end dates.
Eg. let the user enter 2023-02-18 00:00 and compare with `date_column < :end_date` instead of `<=`.

Comment: I am doing a date range with "between".

Comment: You wrote: Have a date/time field in this format in the database: 2018-12-10 15:45:00.075444
This is not correct. If you have a date/time field, there is no format; it is not stored as a string (unless you misuse a VARCHAR field for storing a timestamp) . There only is precision. And it seems that your DB stores fractions of seconds. If you manage to add 59 seconds to the user input, your query will still miss the events in the last second before midnight. That's why using half-open intervals is safer. The performance is the same (at least for Oracle DBs).